# Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 preferences has two of most everything

Tags: cinnamon

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and in Menu > Preferences there are two or more of many items in there. For instance Bluetooth, Displays, Online accounts, power ... I'm using Cinnamon.

How can I remove the duplicated items?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I don't use Cinnamon, but it's possibly the consequence of having **two** desktop environments available. Both of them have their `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`. You could try modifying the ones you don't want to see.

Let's say you have two of "Bluetooth". My .desktop file for "Bluetooth" looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Bluetooth Manager
Comment=Blueman Bluetooth Manager
Icon=blueman
Exec=blueman-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Settings;HardwareSettings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=blueman
```

(I remove extraneous languages.)

Now, if I don't want to see this particular "Bluetooth" while in Cinnamon *and assuming the other DE is Unity*, I'd edit the file for the entry *I don't want to see while in Cinnamon* to look like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Bluetooth Manager
Comment=Blueman Bluetooth Manager
Icon=blueman
Exec=blueman-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Settings;HardwareSettings;
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=blueman
```

Notice the **second-last line** which I've added. That ensures that this particular "Bluetooth" will be seen only when you log into a Unity session.

Obviously, you'd take the usual precaution of backing up important files and you know how to `sudo` edit files. And logging out and logging back in would complete the process.

You can read more about `.desktop` files [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).